# Can a nonlinear system give same solution with distinct set of parameters?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, nonlinear-dynamics

This question comes after experimenting with learning the parameters of a nonlinear system $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = f(\mathbf{x}), f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. If I take a system that has $f = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i\phi_i(\mathbf{x})$, where I know the $\phi_i$'s and try to learn the $a_i$'s from data (trajectories obtained from numerical integration of a known system or from measurements of a physical/biological system with well-studied dynamics) using nonlinear regression (neural network, trust-region methods, Levenberg-Marquadt, etc.) I cannot seem to exactly recover the true $a_i$'s. However, the learned $a_i$'s are doing a great job at predicting unseen initial conditions. From such numerical experiments, I'm reasoning that the solution to this nonlinear system is identical for two sets of parameters, the first being the set of parameters that was used for simulation, and the second being the set of parameters learned from the simulated data. If there is any error in my training data, it would come from the numerical integration. I wonder if numerical integration can bias the solution enough as to throw off the learning process.

My pointed question is this: Can we ever have that a nonlinear system gives identical solutions for two sets of parameters and when might this happen? Are there any known examples of this that are used for teaching/introduction to such behavior?

Comment: If the system under consideration is generally quite stable, solution curves of $\dot x=f(x,a)$, $x(0)=x_0$, $f$ smooth enough in both arguments, will be close-by under small variations of $x_0$ and $a$. You would need to be more precise on how far the learned parameters are from the "true" ones and how "identical" the solutions really are. You get something that is visually identical with an error of $1\%$, for non-stochastic numerical results this is quite large an error.

Comment: If you want an easier, somewhat similar situation, take a degree $d$ from 10 to 50, generate $d$ points in the complex unit circle or square. Then generate the polynomial in monomial expansion that has these points as root and apply a numerical root finder. Compare both root sets. Similar effects can happen, but more rarely, if you take a diagonal matrix with integer diagonal (with some repeated entries), apply integer similarity transforms until the result looks "dense", then apply a numerical eigenvalue algorithm.

Comment: Ah interesting examples, thanks for those. I am going to try them out and try to build some more intuition about this problem